# Method does not override method from its superclass onRewarded()

Tags: android, admob, overriding, rewardedvideoad

so i am trying to implement video reward ads. But when i try to use the onRewarded method to reward the user it says "method does not override method from its superclass"
https://pastebin.com/Hp1zbuWW

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + rewardItem.getType() + "  amount: " +
            rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to implement RewardedVideoAdListener in your activity.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
        private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

            // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
            mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
            mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

            loadRewardedVideoAd();

        }
   private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
             mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
    }
```

Then you can override methods like this.

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```